# CustomCell setImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I made custom UITableViewCell and add UIImageView to the cell.
Then, when I build, the app abend with following log message.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NewsCell setImageView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109139f80'
```

I have this code.

ViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NewsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NewsCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abcde.jpg"];
                break;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

NewsCell.h

```
@interface NewsCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* titleLabel;

@end
```

NewsCell.m

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 44, 40)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
        self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 200, 25)];
        self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

How do I fix it to reflect the custom cell to the tableView?

Comment: Try adding the ImageView to the contentView of the cell instead of directly to the cell

Comment: could you paste here the output of NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([cell class]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **NewsCell.h**, Do you see a warning on **imageView**? The problem is you are trying to replace a **readonly property** with a **readwrite property**. But it will not allow you to do so.

You want to do exactly what what you currently are doing, you may try the declare a different imageView like:-

**NewsCell.h**

```
@interface NewsCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* imageView2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel* titleLabel;

@end
```

**NewsCell.m**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    self.imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 44, 40)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView2];
    self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 5, 200, 25)];
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
}
return self;
}
```

For **ViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NewsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[NewsCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abcde.jpg"];
            break;
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but i think the imageView property is already implemented on a UITableViewCell and it's a readonly property.
Reimplementing it on a subclass might create a conflict.

Try to change the name of your imageView property and let me know if it worked.